# How to solve $\frac{99.5−0.8n}{\sqrt{0.16n}}=-1.645$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\frac{99.5−0.8n}{\sqrt{0.16n}}=-1.645$

Simplifying and I get

$99.5−0.8n+1.645\sqrt{0.16} n^{1/2}=0$

$0.8n-1.645\sqrt{0.16} n^{1/2}-99.5=0$

Can't use quadratic formula.

Comment: `Can't use quadratic formula` Why? It *is* a quadratic in $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Let $n=a^2$ for some real or complex $a$ And then use quadratic formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea you had was on the right track, you just need to continue by squaring both sides.
$$\frac{99.5-0.8n}{\sqrt {0.16n}}=-1.645$$
$$99.5-0.8n=-1.645 \sqrt {0.16n}$$
$$(99.5-0.8n)^2 = (-1.645 \sqrt {0.16n})^2$$
$$9900.25-159.2n+0.64n^2=.432964n$$
$$9900.25-159.632964n+0.64n^2=0$$
From this, you can use any methods you know, such as the quadratic formula.

Comment: Squaring both sides is not necessary at all, and might introduce fictitious solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the absurdly specific
$\dfrac{99.5−0.8n}{\sqrt{0.16n}}=-1.645
$,
consider
$\frac{a−bn}{\sqrt{cn}}=-d
$
with
$a, b, c, d > 0$.

Then
$a-bn
=-d\sqrt{n}
$.
Squaring,
and remembering that
we have to check the roots
because of this,
$a^2-2abn+b^2n^2
=d^2n
$
or
$b^2n^2-(2ab+d^2)n+a^2 = 0$.

Applying the
standard quadratic formula,

$\begin{array}\\
n
&=\dfrac{(2ab+d^2)\pm \sqrt{(2ab+d^2)^2-4a^2b^2}}{2b^2}\\
&=\dfrac{(2ab+d^2)\pm \sqrt{4a^2b^2+4abd^2+d^4-4a^2b^2}}{2b^2}\\
&=\dfrac{(2ab+d^2)\pm \sqrt{4abd^2+d^4}}{2b^2}\\
&=\dfrac{(2ab+d^2)\pm d\sqrt{4ab+d^2}}{2b^2}\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$4ab+d^2 > 0$,
the roots are real;
since
$(2ab+d^2)^2
\gt 4abd^2+d^4
$,
both roots are positive.

Now substitute your parameters.

Comment: Your $c$ disappeared.